# Chart.js stacked area chart grid.borderDash option not working

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I've created a stacked area chart using Chart.js v4.1 and vue-chartjs v5.0. Changing most of the other `grid` options work (e.g., color, display, drawTicks, lineWidth, etc.) but `borderDash` and `borderDashOffset` have no effect.

Here are the options I pass to the Line vue-chartjs component:

```
const options = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        x: {
            grid: {
                display: false,
            },
            ticks: {
                callback: function (val, index) {
                    return index % 2 === 0 ? this.getLabelForValue(val) : '';
                },
            },
        },
        y: {
            border: {
                display: false,
            },
            grid: {
                borderDash: [10, 10],
                drawTicks: false,
            },
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
                callback: function (val, index) {
                    if (index === 0) {
                        return '';
                    }

                    return index % 2 === 0 ? '$' + compactCurrencyFormatter.format(+val) : '';
                },
                padding: 10,
            },
        },
    },
};
```

[image: Stacked Chart]

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/migration/v4-migration.html) the option has been moved from `options.scales[scaleId].grid.borderDash` to `options.scales[scaleId].border.dash` if you make that change it will work fine

Answer (score -2):

try set -> display: true instead of false

```
   border: {
                display: true,
           }
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue